# Why does NGINX load balancer passive health check not detect when upstream server is offline?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, nginx-config

I have an `upstream` block in an Nginx config file. This block lists multiple backend servers across which to load balance requests to.

```
...
upstream backend {
    server backend1.com;
    server backend2.com;
    server backend3.com;
}
...
```

Each of the above 3 backend servers is running a Node application.

1. If I `stop the application process` on backend1 - Nginx recognises this, via passive health check, traffic is only directed to backend2 and backend3, as expected.
2. However, if I `power down the server` on which backend1 is hosted, Nginx does not recognise that it is offline and continues to attempt to send traffic/requests to it. Nginx still tries to direct traffic to the offline server, resulting in an error: `504`.

Can someone shed some light on why this (scenario 2 above) may happen and if there is some further configuration needed that I am missing?

**Update:**
*I'm beginning to wonder if the behaviour I'm seeing is because the above upstream block is located with an `HTTP {}` Nginx context. If backend1 was indeed powered down, this would be a connection error and so (maybe off the mark here, but just thinking aloud) should this be a TCP health check?*

**Update 2:**

`nginx.conf`

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {


       upstream backends {
          server xx.xx.xx.37:3000 fail_timeout=2s;
          server xx.xx.xx.52:3000 fail_timeout=2s;
          server xx.xx.xx.69:3000 fail_timeout=2s;
        }

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##
        ssl_certificate     …
        ssl_certificate_key …
        ssl_ciphers         …;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

`default`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    #server_name ...;
}
server {

    listen              443 ssl;
    listen              [::]:443 ssl;
    # SSL configuration
    ...
    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                 #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    }

        location /api {
            rewrite /api/(.*) /$1  break;
            proxy_pass http://backends;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
         }

        # Requests for socket.io are passed on to Node on port 3000
       location /socket.io/ {
             proxy_http_version 1.1;

             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

             proxy_pass http://backends;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for you to get a `504` is when nginx does HTTP health check it tries to connect to the location(ex: `/` for `200` status code) which you configured. Since the `backend1` is *powered down* and the port is *not listening* and the socket is closed.

It will take some time to get *timeout* exception and hence the `504: gateway timeout`.

It's a different case when you stop the application process.The port will not be listening and it will get `connection refused` which is identified pretty quick and marks the instance as `unavailable`.

To overcome this you can set `fail_timeout=2s` to mark the server as unavailable default is `10` seconds.

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html?&_ga=2.174685482.969425228.1595841929-1716500038.1594281802#fail_timeout

Comment: I've tried setting fail_timeout=2s - but still get 504's

Comment: can you share complete configuration?

Comment: added default file also

Comment: Are you running IIS servers or Linux or???